# Django CSS files not loading correctly in the application

Tags: css, django, docker

In my Django application, I see that the code that is loaded is different from the code written in CSS files. What is the source of this change? How can it be resolved?

Comment: Did you run `manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Try to use another browser or delete the cache of your current browser
you can also check the settings.py and add the path of the css file in :

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=["static/",]
```